# Strange behavior when reading from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

when I'm launching my application and the onResume() method is being run, something goes wrong when reading from my SharedPreferences. This is how the code looks.

```
static double cowCount = 197, income, cowMult = 1;
...
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.cowcount", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    cowCount = sharedPref.getFloat("cowCount", 0);
    cowMult = sharedPref.getFloat("cowMult", 0);
    income = sharedPref.getFloat("income", 0);

 }
...
```

When the code is like this, the application is being frozen. The application consists of a counter, and when I push the button that is supposed to count up, nothing happens.

However, when i comment out the line where i assign a value to the cowMult double from the SharedPreferences, the application doesn't freeze.

```
cowCount = sharedPref.getFloat("cowCount", 0);
// cowMult = sharedPref.getFloat("cowMult", 0);
income = sharedPref.getFloat("income", 0);
```

To be clear, the above works fine.

This is the method called when pushing the button (that is supposed to higher the value of cowCount by one):

```
public void addCow (View view) {
    cowCount = cowCount + cowMult;
    refresh();
}
...
public void refresh () {
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
myTextView.setText("You Have " + String.valueOf((nf.format(cowCount)) + " Cows!"));
}
```

Comment: How does the application "freeze"? Do you have to kill it with Task Manager? Or do you mean that you can press the button, but myTextView doesn't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows:

```
static float cowCount, income, cowMult;
...
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.cowcount", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    cowCount = sharedPref.getFloat("cowCount", 197);
    cowMult = sharedPref.getFloat("cowMult", 1);
    income = sharedPref.getFloat("income", 0);
}
...
```

The second parameter in `SharedPreferences.getFloat()` is a default value that the method will return if the key is not found. With the code you've supplied, If you've not saved the values to `SharedPreferences` properly, those variables will be assigned a value of 0. This is why nothing changes when you press the button; you're adding 0. Check to make sure you are saving to `SharedPreferences` correctly.

Also, there's no point in initializing the variables when you declare them, as they all get assigned a value in the `onResume` method, be it a saved value or a default value.

And, as pointed out by Martin, assign your `TextView` in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: So that's how it works! It didn't feel right to fill in 0... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are strange with the code you have posted

1 why are you calling

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and not

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences( "com.myname.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

2 your onResume should be the following

```
super.onResume();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
cowCount = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPref.getLong("cowCount", 0));
cowMult = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPref.getLong("cowMult", 0));
income = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPref.getLong("income", 0));
```

calling the super.onResume() first before your code (same with all life cycle methods)

EDIT
3. Why are you not just setting your values to be an int (from what you said above they seem to be) or a float which will give you possibly all the precision then you can just get your values using

```
getInt(String key, int defValue)
```

of

```
getFloat(String key, float defValue)
```

Seconded Edit
There are a few strange ways you are doing things in the code that I can see. try the following code and let me know if it fixed the problem (though I can't see how the sharedPreferences would be causing it ). i am presuming the addCow method is being called from an onClickListener

```
//get a reference for your myTextView in the onCreate() method, after declaring your variable

//outside the onCreate method i.e
TextView myTextView;
...
// int onCreate()
 myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);

//you don't need to pass a view parameter, so don't
public void addCow () {
    cowCount = cowCount + cowMult;
    refresh();
}
...
public void refresh () {
  //the way you are getting a string value is also not what I would do either use
  //Float.toString(cowCount) or just
   myTextView.setText("You Have " + cowCount + " Cows!"));
}
```

Hope the issue is gone.

Comment: Okay, I tried with float values, and the same problem persists. Commenting out the "cowMult = ... " line still makes the app run... BTW, I can't use Int because of decimals.

Comment: I don't think I can help any more without seeing how you your button code is working.

Comment: When I change the TextView, declaring it in the beginning of the class and assigning it in onCreate(), the application crashes at startup. Some NullPointException thing.

Comment: Now it works... I had to remove the refresh(); from onCreate(). It's being called 10 times every second anyways, so that isn't a problem... Thank you very much for your help, Martin.